# Silverlight Installation problem

Tags: silverlight-2.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have a problem of silverlight installation.
I am using visual studio 2008 and i have installed silverlight 2.0. It is installed successfully. But it is not display in File--> New Project. So how can i create new silverlight application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd install Silverlight 3.0 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install silverlight tools for VS2008 :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=c22d6a7b-546f-4407-8ef6-d60c8ee221ed&displaylang=en

But I STRONGLY suggest you use VS2010, its a lot better than 2008 for silverlight development.